# URL Rewrite does not act like expected

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

on my whole page links are rewritten from

```
    example.com/test.htm
```

to

```
    example.com/index.php?page=test
```

This works fine, but whenever I want to rewrite a link like

```
    example.com/test/abc.htm
```

and I want it to be

```
    example.com/index.php?page=test&id=abc
```

it doesn`t work at all. Instead (taken from $_SERVER variable) I get:

PHP_SELF is now "test.php/abc.htm"

SCRIPT_NAME is now "/test.php" instead of "/index.php" what it should be

I don`t understand at all why this happens.
My .htacces looks like this:

```
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.htm/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^test/([^/]+)\.htm/?$ /index.php?page=test&id=$1 [L]
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to turn off `MultiViews` options:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)\.htm/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^test/([^/.]+)\.htm/?$ index.php?page=test&id=$1 [L,QSA]
```